# "занял целые 5 лет" or "занял целыx 5 лет"?

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные, падежи, склонение

What's the right way of saying "Этот процесс занял целы**е** пять лет" or "Этот процесс занял целы**x** пять лет". I guess it's accusative inanimate, so it should be целы**е**, am I correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's genitive, so animacy does not play any role here.

Rosenthal in *Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке для работников печати* writes:

> При существительных мужского и среднего рода, зависящих от числительных *два, три, четыре* (а также от составных числительных, оканчивающихся на указанные цифры), определение, находящееся между числительным и существительным, в современном языке ставится, как правило, в форме родительного падежа множественного числа: *два высоких дома, три больших окна, двадцать четыре деревянных стола*. Например:
>
> *...Офицеры ели жадно, без разговоров, наверстывали за два потерянных в боях
>   дня (Шолохов);
>
>   Два других кадровика... воевали меньше (Бубеннов);
>
>   Два крайних окна в первом этаже закрыты изнутри газетными листами... (А. Н. Толстой).*
>
> При существительных женского рода в указанных условиях определение чаще ставится в форме именительного падежа множественного числа: *две большие комнаты*. Например:
>
> *На изгороди из трех жердей сидели три женские фигуры (А. Н. Толстой);
>
>   На платформе прохаживались... две молоденькие чему-то смеявшиеся девушки (Шолохов);
>
>   По этим дорогам двигаются две большие колонны немцев (Бубеннов).*
>
> При наличии перед всем оборотом предлога возможны варианты: *на две равные части / по две столовых ложки.*

and in *Справочник по правописанию, произношению и литературному редактированию*:

> Однако прилагательные *целый, полный, добрый* и некоторые другие обычно употребляются в этом случае в форме родительного падежа: *целых два месяца, целых две недели, полных два ведра, добрых двое суток, лишних три часа.*
>
> Например: *...Принужден был иногда целых три часа стоять, прижавшись к стене (Пушкин)*; *Да и бил он меня каких-нибудь месяца два (Достоевский)*.

So *целый*, if applied to the noun, would be put into pl. gen. for masculine and neuter nouns, and into pl. nom. for feminine nouns:

- *Этот процесс занял пять целых лет*
- *Этот процесс занял три целы**е** минуты* (fem. noun, adjective in pl. nom.)

But for the idiomatic constructs with *целый, полный, добрый, лишний, жалкий* etc. which  define the numeral rather than the noun (and hence are put before the numeral, not the noun), the exception from the second quote applies:

- *Этот процесс занял целых пять лет*
- *Этот процесс занял целы**х** три минуты* (fem. noun, but adjective in pl. gen.)

This rule is not strict and is often violated. These queries

> целый nom,pl
>   на расстоянии 1 от два  NUM
>   на расстоянии 1 от S,f

and

> целый gen,pl
>   на расстоянии 1 от два  NUM
>   на расстоянии 1 от S,f

yield 45 and 141 entries in the corpus, accordingly (more than a third usage cases are wrong according to Rosenthal).

Comment: @brilliant: Actually, I messed up the answer in first, please see the edit. It does not change the usage in your case, though :)

Comment: I am confused by your last two examples that follow the line "This rule is not strict and is often violated. These queries".

Comment: @brilliant: the queries against the corpus. I can't paste the URL here, it's too large or whatever.

Comment: @Quassnoi Neither understand I the last examples.