# Agreement of numerals, adjectives and nouns

Tags: числительные

I'm trying to figure out how numerals agree with adjectives and nouns... @_@
I've found this sentence:
Я нашла тридцать шесть старые газеты
I'm not sure it is correct... Shouldn't it be:
Я нашла тридцать шесть старых газет?

старые газеты is in accusative case... I know that газета is an inanimate noun, but shouldn't numerals from пять up be followed by nouns and adjectives in genitive plural case?
Or do I still have to observe the difference between animate/inanimate nouns?

Sorry for my terrible explanation (probably dued to my poor english)... still, I hope someone can help me clearing this doubt!
Thanks in advance for your attention! :)

Comment: Related question: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/511/how-to-decline-adjectives-modifying-feminine-nouns-after-2-3-4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You understand everything correctly. The first sentence is incorrect.(Я нашла тридцать шесть #старые газеты#).

> Я нашла **старые газеты**.

Here we observe the rule of the accusative for inanimate nouns. But when you say

> Я нашла тридцать шесть **старых газет**.

It should be genitive plural because of "шесть".

Read more here.

[Я вижу + numeral + noun - governed by what case?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/13618/%d0%af-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d1%83-numeral-noun-governed-by-what-case)